# Programmatically Creating fieldset, ol/ul and li tags in ASP.Net, C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, tags, fieldset

I need to write an ASP.Net form which will produce the following HTML:

```
<fieldset>   
<legend>Contact Details</legend>   
<ol>   
<li>   
<label for="name">Name:</label>   
<input id="name" name="name" class="text" type="text" />   
</li>   
<li>   
<label for="email">Email address:</label>   
<input id="email" name="email" class="text" type="text" />   
</li>   
<li>   
<label for="phone">Telephone:</label>   
<input id="phone" name="phone" class="text" type="text" />   
</li>   
</ol>   
</fieldset>
```

However, the fields which are to be added to the form will be determined at runtime, so I need to create the fieldset at runtime and add an ordered list and listitems to it, with labels, textboxes, checkboxes etc as appropriate.

I can’t find standard ASP.Net objects which will create these tags.

For instance, I’d like to do something like the following in C#:

```
FieldSet myFieldSet = new FieldSet();
myFieldSet.Legend = “Contact Details”;
OrderedList myOrderedList = new OrderedList();

ListItem listItem1 = new ListItem();
ListItem listItem2 = new ListItem();
ListItem listItem3 = new ListItem();

// code here which would add labels and textboxes to the ListItems

myOrderedList.Controls.Add(listItem1);
myOrderedList.Controls.Add(listItem2);
myOrderedList.Controls.Add(listItem3);

myFieldSet.Controls.Add(myOrderedList);

Form1.Controls.Add(myFieldSet);
```

Are there any standard ASP.Net objects which can produce this, or is there some other way of achieving the same result?

Matt

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can try this:

```
Panel myFieldSet = new Panel();
myFieldSet.GroupingText= “Contact Details”;
HtmlGenericControl myOrderedList = new HtmlGenericControl("ol");

HtmlGenericControl listItem1 = new HtmlGenericControl ("li");
HtmlGenericControl listItem2 = new HtmlGenericControl ("li");
HtmlGenericControl listItem3 = new HtmlGenericControl ("li");

// code here which would add labels and textboxes to the ListItems

myOrderedList.Controls.Add(listItem1);
myOrderedList.Controls.Add(listItem2);
myOrderedList.Controls.Add(listItem3);

myFieldSet.Controls.Add(myOrderedList);

Form1.Controls.Add(myFieldSet);
```

Comment: Thanks, Rewinder.  That works great.  Instead of a Panel, I'm using the following control: http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/BuildingGroupBoxControl.aspx - thanks again.

Comment: This was helpful. Create the ol, create the li. Add the li to the ol. Add the ol to the panel.

Answer (score 0):

> Per the answer above, I had an instance where an array proved to be useful as shown here. Note: I created an unordered list in the aspx code with id="ulNoTree".

```
int NumFloorsCt = 10;
LinkButton[] rgBL;
HtmlGenericControl[] rgLI;

/// <summary>
/// set up an array of LinkButtons with "li" controls
/// - each LinkButton click is handled by the same event handler
/// </summary>
void SetUpLinkButtons(List<FLOOR> listFloorRecs)
{
  NumFloorsCt = 10;
  rgBL = new LinkButton[NumFloorsCt];
  rgLI = new HtmlGenericControl[NumFloorsCt];

  for (int i = 0; i < NumFloorsCt; i++)
  {
    rgBL[i] = new LinkButton();
    rgBL[i].ID = LB_ID_prefix + listFloorRecs[i].ID;
    rgBL[i].Click += new System.EventHandler(LB_fp_Click);
    rgBL[i].Text = listFloorRecs[i].DESCRIP;
    rgBL[i].ToolTip = "Click here to display floor info";

    rgLI[i] = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
    rgLI[i].Controls.Add(rgBL[i]);

    ulNoTree.Controls.Add(rgLI[i]);
  }
}

/// <summary>
/// event handler for any of the link buttons
/// </summary>
protected void LB_fp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)(sender);
  // do your action here
}
```